# filter Sequelize belongsToMany get<Association> association table

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am working with Sequelize 4.37.10 and it works great.
Unfortunately the documentation is not perfect in my opinion. So it lacks a bit of describing the belongsToMany possibilities.

I have the following problem:

I defined my tables like this:

```js
const Department = db.define('department', {
  name: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
  shortName: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false}
})

const Employee = db.define('employee', {
  title: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
  name: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
  surname: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false},
  .
  .
  role: {type: Sequelize.STRING}
})
```

Then I associated the tables like this:

```js
const EmployeeDepartments = db.define('employeeDepartments', {
  manager: {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false}
})

Department.belongsToMany(Employee, {through: EmployeeDepartments})
Employee.belongsToMany(Department, {through: EmployeeDepartments})
```

Now i want to get all department employees with the manager field set to true.
The creation was no problem, but the select is a problem for me.

I tried the following with no luck:

```js
department.getEmployees({where: {manager: true}})
```

I also thought of scopes but I don't know how to design that properly.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funnily, I was just looking for the exact same thing, and the only result was your question from a few hours ago...

I solved it by now, what you need is the following:

```
department.getEmployees({ through: { where: { manager: true } } })
```

You can also get all employees of a `department` of which you only have the `id`:

```
const department = Department.build( { id: departmentId } );
// proceed as above
```

Comment: Nice! Sad to know that the [Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html#instance-method-get) does not tell anything about the `through` option. Thank you!

In my opinion, the second code line is easier by using `Department.findById(departmentId)`

Comment: The problem with that approach is that you hit the DB. The `build` doesn't.

Comment: Also, you may run into this problem that you cannot really remove the association field `departmentEmployee` from the resulting employees (see this issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3664). I solved this with `employees.forEach( e => delete e.dataValues['department_employee'] )`

Answer (score 2):

```
department.getEmployees({where: {manager: true}})
```

**change this code with this.**

```
department.getEmployees(      
  include:{
    model: employeedepartments, // your employee departments model name
    {where: {manager: true},      
    required:true, 
  }
})
```

**You have to just add include in your query**

Comment: include expects an array

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple answer myself after searching a while.

When using `belongsToMany` Sequelize does use a join to get data from the second table (I knew that).

I had the option to use the following syntax:

```
department.getEmployees({where: {'$employeeDepartments.manager$': true}})
```

I found that from a page on google but unfortunately I lost the url.
Maybe this helps someone with a similar problem.